# Object gets passed by reference to array (CodeIgniter, DataMapper)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Here's my code:

```
$get = $this->auth->current_user()->author->get_iterated();
foreach($get as $page) $pages[] = $page;

foreach($pages as $page) var_dump($page->title);
```

Now, if there are 2 pages that the user is author of, the latter `foreach`-loop will output the title of the last page 2 times.

I have a reason not to output the titles in the first loop. However, I don't want to paste the whole code here, as the problem can be seen in the small code above.

It seems like `$page` is passed by reference to the array `$pages`. Is it possible to *not* do this, and save the static object instead?

Comment: Can you add the output of `var_dump` for `$pages` and `$page` between the loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `clone` keyword/magic method. This'll create a separate copy of the object, which you can save or pass to wherever you need it...